# Query Active Directory users who are managed by given manager's sAMAccountName

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to search active directory users whose manager's username is given in the search request, but I always get 0 records regardless of the manager's username I pass.

To achieve this, I executed the following LDAP query:

```
(manager=sAMAccountName=Administrator)
```

I also tried by manager's common name like this:

```
(manager=cn=John Smith)
```

Can anyone write me an LDAP query that returns all users whose manager's sAMAccountName=administrator ?

Comment: without providing what or how you tried to solve this problem, not many people will help you here

Answer (score 2):

`manager` has distinguished name syntax, therefore, if `manager` is used in an assertion, the full DN must be used as the value. Neither of the examples you gave meet this criteria. You must correct the filter to use a distinguished name.

The syntax of manager:

```
attributeTypes: ( 0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.10 NAME 'manager'
  EQUALITY distinguishedNameMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.12
  X-ORIGIN 'RFC 4524' )
```

To determine the syntax, use the [LDAP Parameters Assignment](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ldap-parameters/ldap-parameters.xml) page. On that page, search for the OID following the `SYNTAX` keyword (`1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.12`). That shows that it's DN syntax. Also, the `EQUALITY` matching rule is `distinguishedNameMatch`.

An example of an assertion in a filter using the correct syntax:

```
manager=cn=Manager Number One,ou=managers,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
```

All attributes values used in an assertion must have the syntax defined for that attribute type in the schema.

### Update

Verify the entries exist with a known good tool such as `ldapsearch` to ensure that the correct parameters are known for the search request. For example:

```
$ ldapsearch -h hostname -p port -b 'dc=sahara,dc=local' \
  -D [your-bind-dn] -w [your-bind-dn-password]         \
  -s sub                                               \
  '(manager=cn=Izzeddeen Alkarajeh,ou=managers,ou=people,dc=sahara,dc=local)' \
   1.1
```

If this search returns no entries, check with the LDAP administrators to ensure that the BIND DN in use has permission o read those entries.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/mastering-ldap-search-filters.html)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)

Comment: Dear @terry-gardner
Thanks for your valuable comment. It looks like you are taking my hand to the right way. Hope you do me a little more favor.
Now I have a domain named "sahara.local", and I want to search for users managed by "Izzeddeen Al Karajeh".

So based on your above answer, I used the following query:
"code"(manager=cn=Izzeddeen Alkarajeh,ou=managers,ou=people,dc=sahara,dc=local)

Which returned zero result. Am I missing something here? Or the query has to take another form?

Comment: First link is dead

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I figured out a way to do this in C# that I have yet to find on stackoverflow.

```
using (var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain.com"))
using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "samAccountName"))
{
    DirectoryEntry de = (DirectoryEntry)user.GetUnderlyingObject();

    if (de.Properties["directReports"].Count != 0)
        managedFound = de.Properties["directReports"];
}
```

This will give you a list of strings that you can then parse out the `CN` using this:

```
managedUserName = Regex.Match(managedFound.ToString(), @"CN[=].*?[,]").Value.Replace("CN=", "").Replace(",", "");
```

Then, the following to get the User properties:

```
UserPrincipal managedUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.Name, managedUserName);
```